# .NET MVC JQuery function is not getting fired in table row click event

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have table data in UI. I want to display data in a div in the same page when I click the Details link in the row. The JQuery function is not getting fired in when I click on details link in any row.

Below is my code:

Model view class:

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
     public Item item { get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<Item> items { get; set; }
}
```

UI Code:

```
@model Medhub.Models.ItemViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "View";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>View</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "CreateEdit", new { controller = "Item" }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
</p>
<table align="center" height="10%" width="90%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="Items">
                <table style="vertical-align:top; height:200px" width="100%">
                    <tr style="height:20px">
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayName("Name")
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayName("Description")
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayName("Item Type")
                        </th>
                    </tr>

                    @if (Model != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in Model.items)
                        {
                            <tr style="height:15px">
                                <td>
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.ItemId)
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Name)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Description)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Type)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "CreateEdit", new { id = item.ItemId }) |
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Item", new { id = item.ItemId }) |
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ItemId })
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    }
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="ItemDetails">
                @if (Model.item != null)
                {
                    Html.RenderPartial("Details", Model.item);
                }
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("div.Items a").click(function (e) {
            //e.preventDefault();
            var url = this.ref;
            $("#ItemDetails").load(url);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controller code:

```
List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
// GET: Item
public ActionResult Item(int id = 0)
{
      ItemViewModel itemVM = new ItemViewModel();
      itemVM.items = GetItems();
      if (id > 0)
      itemVM.item = itemVM.items.FirstOrDefault(u => u.ItemId == id);
      return View(itemVM);
}
```

Any clues?

Comment: You're defining `div.Items a` selector which means `div` tag with class `Items` & `a` tag inside it, but I can't find any div element which has class `Items`. Try change the selector to something like `$('div[id^="Items"] a')`.

Comment: Thanks. Will try and let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are waiting for clicks on a class called Items. This is the reason the jquery code is not being fired. You should have

```
$("div#Items a").click(function (e) {
```

Secondly, you need to check the attribut href, not ref. Also, prevent default needs to be there, otherwise you just reload your page

```
e.preventDefault();
var url = this.href;
```

You don't need the renderpartial in the page, just leave it empty:

```
<div id="ItemDetails">
</div>
```

While your logic kind of works, the way the url is loaded causes the entire page to be loaded into the ItemDetails section. I'd suggest that in your controller, you'd create a separate method for the details:

```
    public ActionResult Details(int id) {
        Item item = GetItem(id);

        return View(item);
    }

    private Item GetItem(int id) {
        return new Item() { Details = "details here" };
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Pitchmatt. Will try and let you know.

Comment: Guys.. I want to do paging in asp.NET MVC. While there are articles I have seen. One of them is PagedList.mvc. What is the best approach?